# Escaping dots in bash variables

Tags: bash, shell

I want to escape dots from an IP address in Unix shell scripts (bash or ksh) so that I can match the exact address in a grep command.

```
echo $ip_addr | sed "s/\./\\\./g"
```

works (outputs 1\.2\.3\.4), but

```
ip_addr_escaped=`echo $ip_addr | sed "s/\./\\\./g"`
echo $ip_addr_escaped
```

Doesn't (outputs 1.2.3.4)

How can I correctly escape the address?

**Edit:**
It looks like

```
ip_addr_escaped=`echo $ip_addr | sed "s/\./\\\\\\\./g"`
```

works, but that's clearly awful!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`bash` parameter expansion supports pattern substitution, which will look (slightly) cleaner and doesn't require a call to `sed`:

```sh
echo ${ip_addr//./\\.}
```

Comment: It does for me. Also, you never mentioned `ksh`.

Comment: Sorry - you're right. I must have tested it wrongly. (I did mention ksh - but not in the question title)

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, processing of backslashes is one of the strange quoting-related behaviors of backticks `` `...` ``. Rather than fighting with it, it's better to just use `$(...)`, which the same except that its quoting rules are smarter and more intuitive. So:

```
ip_addr_escaped=$(echo $ip_addr | sed "s/\./\\\./g")
echo $ip_addr_escaped
```

But if the above is really your exact code — you have a parameter named `ip_addr`, and you want to replace `.` with `\.` — then you can use Bash's built-in `${parameter/pattern/string}`  notation:

```
ip_addr_escaped=${ip_addr//./\\.}
```

Or rather:

```
grep "${ip_addr//./\\.}" [FILE...]
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the ".", which doesn't have special meaning in a glob pattern.

Comment: @chepner: \*tests\* You're right! That notation looks so much like Perl or sed to me, that I always forget that it just uses glob notation. My version does work (I tested it before posting), but yeah, I'll remove the extra backslashes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Replace the double quotes with single quotes.